# Parse Database query

Tags: parse-platform

I am an Parse newbie,

I have one class and one row. 
Within that row I want to be able to have like a drop down, so it only has about 5 choices. I want these choices to be in another table. This other table is to have the choices and also images.

Images and other tables are easy. I just want a link between the two tables and hopefully some sort of drop down which reads the results from the other table.

Hope anyone can help me.

Comment: did you try anything ?

Comment: I tried the pointer, but it don't get what it does.

Comment: You should show your code snippet.